# What did the Greeks call their gods while under Roman rule?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, ancient-greece, religious-history, greek-mythology

I read [this question](https://www.quora.com/Did-ancient-Greeks-take-Greek-mythology-literally) and it made me think. The Romans "inherited" the Greek gods, they just gave them new names, but what happened in actual Greece after the Roman conquest of Greece? Did the Greek refer to their gods with Roman or Greek names? Any other changes in how the Greeks worshipped their gods after the conquest that can be derived from Roman religious influence?

Comment: Wikipedia has something on this: [Ancient Greek religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_religion#Roman_Empire). Perhaps you could edit your question to clarify what is lacking there. Otherwise, I fear this will be closed as too basic (and someone has already downvoted...)

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Does this question really make sense?  Zeus by any other name would still hurl lightning bolts :-)

Comment: Southern Baptists in the US worship "God".  Italian Catholics worship "Dio".  Southern Baptists have different practices of worship than Italian Catholics and the two groups differ on many finer points of the religion.  Despite that, both parties will tell you that "Dio" is just another word for "God" and they both worship the same entity.   Greeks just saw "Jove" as another name for "Zeus"

Comment: @GorttheRobot Upvoted. _Allah_ also means _god_ but both words are used in English and Italian to make a distinction.

Comment: How is this not too basic?  How is this appropriate for History?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Too basic - why? It's a quite narrow and specific question IMO.

Comment: The question contains no research, and can be answered by [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_Gods_and_their_Roman_counterparts)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace No it can't. I already read that article but you clearly haven't read my question. Or please quote the answer. I am not holding my breath.

Comment: It is definitely too basic for the site

Comment: Jupiter literally means Zeus Pater (father Zeus),  so exact same god as Zeus.

Comment: @ed.hank But that is not the question. I was wondering if the Greeks started to use Latinized names (or changed their religious practises in any other way that can be derived to Roman influence) for their gods after the Roman conquest or kept using the Greek names. Why does everyone have problem with their reading skills?

Comment: To expand on @ed.hank The "ju" in "Jupiter" is literally comes from the same indo-European root word as "Zeus".  It's analogous to the English "God" and the German "Gott".  It's too basic because it should be obvious that if the Greeks stopped using the word Zeus, then the name wouldn't be in common parlance [today](https://hades.gamepedia.com/Zeus)

Comment: I think if this was specified to exclude the names of the gods and focus on the practice of the religion, it could be reopened. It's clear that Greek continued to be used as the language, as it even became the language of Roman administration in the east, but the Wikipedia doesn't describe if Roman practices affected Greek style of worship.

Comment: @GorttheRobot: Yes, Ζεῦ πάτερ and Iū-piter and [Dyauspitar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyaus) all mean "heavenly father". The same root can be found in the Latin *deus*. **But** the *analogous* word in the Germanic language subfamily would be [Tiwaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BDr#Etymology) and its variants. The word "God" / "Gott" (which is again specific to the Germanic language subfamily) means "an invoked one"; as such it is *much* less specific and refers to *any* god-like being, not the figure of Sky Father in particular.

Answer (score 6):

The Romans did not "inherit" the Greek gods.  The Romans practiced the *[interpretatio romana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretatio_graeca#Interpretatio_romana)* whereby they identified foreign gods as being their own under different names, just as the Greeks practices *interpretatio graeca*.

Religiously, they tended to use their own terms in their own languages, although it was not unknown for a Roman in Greece to write an inscription commemorating a sacrifice to "Jupiter, whom the Greeks call Zeus."  It was also not known for epithets to be transferred -- as the Egyptians called Thoth "Thrice Great", Romans and Greeks would refer to Mercury "ter Maximus" or Hermes "Trismegistus."

Comment: The Romans was heavily influenced by Greek culture. Didn't e.g., Caesar speak Greek when talking to his fellow patricians? Sicily was a Greek colony (Archimedes was based there) at a time Rome was a small village with huts made of dirt. I think it is an oversimplification to claim that the Romans just reinterpreted the Greek deities, it was probably more of religious appropriation.

Comment: Roman practices were and remained sufficiently different to make it clear they were maintaining their own albeit with some influence.  Mars remained a vitally important god despite the lesser importance of Ares in Greek religion.

Comment: Well, compare that to how Catholics and protestants emphasize Mary (mother of Jesus).